# Linear inequalities with one unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

$$3x+\frac{2}{4} \leq x+\frac{7}{2}$$ What is the solution to the inequality?

I started multiplying both sides by 4
which gave me $3x+2\leq14$.
Then I subtracted two from both sides obtaining
$$3x\leq12$$
which then I divided by 3 to obtain the solution
$$x\leq4\ .$$
This solution does not match for my possible answers on my practice guide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply every term by four, not only the constants, that is $$3x+\frac{2}{4}\le x + \frac{7}{2} \iff 12x+2\le 4x + 14\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract $x+\frac{2}{4}$ on both sides...
$$3x+\frac{2}{4} \leq x+\frac{7}{2} \iff 2x \leq \frac{7}{2}-\frac{2}{4} = \frac{14}{4}-\frac{2}{4} = \frac{12}{4} = 3$$
and finally divide both sides by $2$ to find $x \leq \frac{3}{2}$.

Note:

> I started multiplying both sides by $4$ which gave me $3x+2\leq 14$.

You should have got $12x+2 \leq 4x+14 \iff 8x \leq 12$...

Comment: That would be subtract $x + \frac{2}{4}$.

Comment: true, thanks...